# flutter tab bar view inside scroll able column

Tags: flutter

I need to implement a tab bar in following formation:

1. AppBar
2. DropDown
3. TabBar
4. Slider
5. TabBarView

Problem is: I'm putting everything from dropdown to tab bar view inside a column which goes inside a `SingleChildScrollView`. Which does not work.

My code:

```
  late TabController _tabController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _merchantProducts = _getMerchantData();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        ...app bar
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: _buildItems(context),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItems(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 15),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 20),
          child: AddressDropDown(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          indicatorColor: CustomColors.primary,
          labelColor: CustomColors.primary,
          unselectedLabelColor: CustomColors.grey,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: 'All',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Popular',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Center(
          child: AdSliderCard(),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        TabBarView(
           controller: _tabController,
           children: [
              _buildMerchantProductList(context),
              _buildMerchantProductList(context),
           ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMerchantProductList(BuildContext context) {
    return ListContainer(
      data: _merchantProducts,
      isHorizontal: false,
      isScrollable: true,
    );
  }
}
```

How to solve the issue?

**UPDATE:** I can make the TabBarView scrollable without an issue. I need to make the entire page scrollable.

Comment: Have you tried using a second column to wrap your column with? And then extracting the dropdown and the tabbar out to the new column?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. `Column( children: [Column(children: [widgets])])`?

Comment: `Column( children: [AddressDropdown(), Column(children: [widgets]), TabBar()])`

Comment: In my case I have to do `AddressDropdown, TabBar, widget, TabBarView` my tabs are working fine. It's the tab bar view i need help with

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) and [`SliverFillRemaining`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverFillRemaining-class.html) for `TabBarView`.

[image]

```dart
  return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("A"),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(
              [
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: dropdownValue,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                  elevation: 16,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                  underline: Container(
                    height: 2,
                    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                  ),
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      dropdownValue = newValue!;
                    });
                  },
                  items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
                      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabs: const [
                    Tab(
                      text: 'All',
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: 'Popular',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Slider(value: .3, onChanged: (v) {}),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillViewport(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed([
              TabBarView(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                //*
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ...List.generate(
                          33,
                          (index) => Text(
                            "tab A: $index",
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ...List.generate(
                          33,
                          (index) => Text(
                            "tab B: $index",
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Updated based on question update.

Comment: thanks a lot man. it worked except https://ibb.co/HpMt5hp, this issue. Any idea on how to fix this? I tried your code but if the TabBarView has anything that exceeds the page height I get pixel overflow. My buildMerchantProducts has a listview inside it.

Comment: use `SingleChildScrollView` with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`  for each `TabBarView` child.

Comment: Done, but unfortunately still no luck : https://ibb.co/QKDX501

Comment: As I see it, there are three physics involved, TabBarView, SingleChildScrollView and my ListView. I'll do a trial and error run to see if anything works

Comment: `SliverFillViewport` will take available spaces but while it is beyond the screen size, you need to use ScrollableWidget, but we already have one, therefore `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240505/discussion-between-fahim-hoque-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Answer (score 0):

In your builditems, better way to achieve what you need is to use CustomScrollView:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SizedBox(height: 15),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 20),
        child: AddressDropDown(),
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SizedBox(height: 20),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        child: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          indicatorColor: CustomColors.primary,
          labelColor: CustomColors.primary,
          unselectedLabelColor: CustomColors.grey,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabs: [
            Tab(
              text: 'All',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Popular',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        child: Center(
          child: AdSliderCard(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SizedBox(height: 20),
    ),
    SliverFillRemaining(
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          _buildMerchantProductList(context),
          _buildMerchantProductList(context),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: The issue with this code is that one would have to scroll TabBarView and other widgets separately. I want to scroll the entire page altogether

Comment: what's your content for _buildMerchantProductList? ListView or GridView?

Comment: It's a listview with horizontal scroll. It's actually a listview inside a listview. you can check this picture to get a better idea: https://ibb.co/5rxMHC0